How to execute command from Java in a Docker container?
I am trying to execute chmod command from Java in a running Docker container:
String cmd = "docker exec -it " + POSTGRES_CONTAINER_NAME + " bash -c 'chmod +x /tmp/dump.sh'";

  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
  for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
    LOGGER.debug("L:{}", line);
  }

There is a problem because execution flag is not set (and I am not getting any message from docker exec).
docker exec -it postgres_intm bash -c "ls -la /tmp/dump.sh"
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 134 Jun  4 20:59 /tmp/dump.sh

When I call a chmod from command line manually, an execution permission is set correctly:
docker exec -it postgres_intm bash -c 'chmod +x /tmp/dump.sh'

docker exec -it postgres_intm bash -c "ls -la /tmp/dump.sh"  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 134 Jun  4 20:59 /tmp/dump.sh

Q: What am I doing wrong that Java code doesn't set a execution permission?

check the documentation of exec(String): "Deprecated.
This method is error-prone and should not be used, the corresponding method exec(String[]) or ProcessBuilder should be used instead. The command string is broken into tokens using only whitespace characters. For an argument with an embedded space, such as a filename, this can cause problems as the token does not include the full filename." (I also believe it does NOT consider ' or ")

(not sure if that is the problem here since using bash to interpret the second part of the command, but the use of ProcessBuilder is better anyway IMHO)

Does this answer your question? Why does Runtime.exec(String) work for some but not all commands?

Is the JAVA Environment inside docker or outside docker?

(Should this chmod command be in your image's Dockerfile?  Fixing executables' permissions doesn't seem like something you should need to manually do.)

@user85421 The problem was not only in exec(String) as you mentioned but in options for docker exec as well - see my answer, thanks!

Now I use ProcessBuilder as mentioned @user85421, because exec(String) is error-prone and is deprecated. With ProcessBuilder I finally got all errors by process.getErrorStream() and the problem seems to be in my docker exec options -it, that -i means "interactive" so console was listening for another inputs; when I use -t only command is executed properly.
This is final docker exec code that works as expected:
 final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

      processBuilder.command(
          "docker",
          "exec",
          "-t",
          POSTGRES_CONTAINER_NAME,
          "/bin/bash",
          "-c",
          "pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -E utf8 --no-acl --no-privileges --no-owner database > /tmp/host/dump.sql");


Edit: another option is to use Apache Commons Exec.
